# Laravel + Vue.js - возможна ли динамическая подгрузка разметки

Tags: laravel, vue.js

При сборке, все Vue-компоненты собираются в один JS-файл и загружаются при начальной загрузке (включая их разметку). Есть ли способы динамической подгрузки разметки по мере необходимости? (К примеру, если разметки еще нету, то она отправляется сервером вместе с данными)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только была статья на [vue с lasy load](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/) таким образом компоненты будут загружаться по надобности

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="isModalVisible = true">Open modal</button>
    <modal-window v-if="isModalVisible" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isModalVisible: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    ModalWindow: () => import('./ModalWindow.vue')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Все выходит, только почему-то chunk-и кладутся в корень паблика, а не к основному js

Comment: А кто мешает пути поменять ? Это только пример.

Comment: Я о расположении скомпилированного скрипта при таком подходе. Он кладется Webpack-ом в корень паблика